# How to update Nvidia driver safely in Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, opengl

**Problem Background:**

I'm facing problem in rendering 3D objects that is using [Pyrender](https://github.com/mmatl/pyrender). Pyrender needs OpenGL (EGL or Mesa), all the Graphics files (GL, GLE and GLX) should be in usr/lib/nvidia or usr/lib32 same as this issue [how to use opengl with nvidia drivers?] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55585944/how-to-use-opengl-with-nvidia-drivers)

I have tested my problem in two different computers

First PC configuration (Server)

- Ubuntu 16.04
- RTX2080Ti
- Nvidia Driver: 418.74

Second PC configuration (Local PC)

- Ubuntu 16.04
- RTX2060
- Nvidia Driver: 440.31

In server having 418.74 driver, there is no any Graphics file (GL, GLE or GLX) in above mentioned directory but in my local PC having driver 440.31, all the files are in mentioned directory and rendering is working fine in my local PC but I need rendering in server. I also installed Mesa and other related libraries in server but nothing is working for me. I read many solutions from Nvidia and Stackoverflow and it seems that there is driver version problem. So my questions are

- How I can update Nvidia driver from 418.74 to 440.31?
- If I remove/delete previous driver and install new driver then will
  it cause any problem with CUDA or other libraries for all users of
  server?
- If there is no solution for above questions then Is there any
  solution regarding missing graphic files?